# Determinar a quantidade de vezes que um numero poderá se repetir em uma array

Tags: php

Preciso criar um sistema de sorteio onde um determinado numero sera obrigado a aparecer 3 vezes em uma array.

Tem que possuir 9 posições aleatórias de 1 a 6 e somente um numero 1 pode repetir 3 vezes, os outros no máximo 2 vezes

Exemplo: array(**1**,2,**1**,3,5,3,6,5,**1**);

Da forma que pensei em trabalhar esta totalmente ineficiente, pois não tenho nenhum controle do numero que ira repetir, nem quantas vezes

```
$numeros_jogadas = rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6).",".rand(1, 6);
```

Comment: Poderia postar o que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Eu estava tentando de uma forma aleatória, mas depois percebi que a logica precisaria que um numero especifico repetisse , dai então eu fiquei perdido, vou editar e colocar o que tentei

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas não vi que era PHP e escrevi em C#. Mas se quiser dar uma olhada, o código tá aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jWxK3t

Comment: @CypherPotato,CORRIGINDO - E quase o que preciso, so faltou determinar o numero que sera obrigado a repetir vou ver sua logica e tentar adaptar para o que preciso com as funçoes do PHP

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Na linha `gerado == 1` você pode substituir por qualquer número.

Comment: Você pretende fazer isso para outros números né? Por exemplo, número 1 se repete x, número 2 se repete y, etc...?

Comment: @CypherPotato, a ideia seria, mas creio que se eu consegir com apenas um numero ja me atende

Comment: Um número é **obrigado** a se repetir 3 vezes ou **até** 3 vezes?

Comment: Um numero e obrigado a repetir 3 vezes, poderia ser um numero especifico = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma idéia é já definir de início o número 3 vezes repetido e já inclui-los na array:

```
$num3 = rand(1, 6);
$array = array();
array_push($array,$num3,$num3,$num3);
```

Depois fazer um `while` para preencher as outras 6 posições com números aleatórios diferentes do número que já foi definido 3 vezes, e no meio usar um `for` para contar quantas ocorrências do novo número se encontra na array, e só inserir este novo número se não houver mais de 2 ocorrências dele. Veja o código completo com comentários explicativos:

```
<?php
function nums(){

   $num3 = rand(1, 6); // número que irá se repetir 3 vezes
   $array = array(); // declara a array
   // insere o valor nas 3 primeiras posições da array
   array_push($array,$num3,$num3,$num3);

   // enquanto a areray não tiver 9 posições
   while(sizeof($array) < 9){
      // número aleatório de 1 a 6
      $num = rand(1, 6);

      // se este número for diferente do número repetido 3 vezes
      // se for igual, o while continua rodando
      if($num3 != $num){

         // contador para contar ocorrências
         $conta = 0;

         // verifica ocorrências do número
         for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($array); $x++){
            if($array[$x] == $num) $conta++;
         }

         // se houver menos de 2 ocorrências
         // adiciona o número na array
         if($conta < 2) $array[] = $num;

      }

   }

   // randomiza a ordem dos elementos
   shuffle($array);

   // retorna a array
   return $array;
}

// printa a array na tela
print_r(nums());
?>
```

**[Veja o IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Z1v3pa)**

Depois que array estiver formada com as 9 posições, a linha `shuffle($array);` embaralha os elementos. Teste quantas vezes quiser e perceba que apenas 1 número possui 3 ocorrências, e o restante são diferentes e só conseguem se repetir no máximo 2 vezes.

Answer (score 1):

Usando a ideia apresentada em C# pelo @CypherPotato eu fiz a implementação PHP.

A ideia é colocar em um loop pra gerar o array das 9 posições e ir conferindo a quantidade de valores já inseridos e só inserir caso ainda não tenha atingido o limite, caso seja adicionado o valor ao array o loop é incrementado em +1.

```
    $arr = array(1, 1, 1); //inicializa o array com o número obrigatório preenchido
    $i = 4; //inicia o inteiro controlador da quantidade de posições preenchidas no array

    //laço de repetição para garantir as 9 posições do array. O $i é incrementado sempre que for adicionado um valor ao array.
    while($i <= 9){ 
        $valor = rand(1, 6); //gera o valor randômico de 1 a 6

        //Verifica se já teve alguma ocorrência do valor gerado no array
        if(isset(array_count_values($arr)[$valor])){

            //caso o valor gerado não seja 1, verifica se já teve as 2 ocorrências para esse valor. Caso não tenha as 2 ocorrências, adiciona o valor ao array
            if(array_count_values($arr)[$valor] < 2){
                array_push($arr, $valor);
                $i++;
            }
        }else{
            //Se ainda não houver nenhuma ocorrência para o valor, adiciona ele ao array diretamente
            array_push($arr, $valor);
            $i++;
        }
    }

    shuffle($arr); //randomiza os valores do array

    print_r($arr);
```

O `array_count_values` conta as ocorrências de cada posição do array e agrupa, retornando o valor como um índice e a quantidade como valor desse índice. Exemplo:

```
$array = [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2];
```

O resultado do `array_count_values` seria

```
print_r($arr);

[
    1 => 3,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 1
]
```

Usando como exemplo esse outro array

```
$arr = ["banana", "maçã", "banana", "pêra", "banana", "pêra"];
```

Teriamos como resultado do `array_count_values`

```
print_r($arr);

[
    "banana" => 3,
    "maçã" => 1,
    "pêra" => 2
]
```

Comment: Obrigado @JrD eu estava tentando recriar aqui, mas sempre quebrando a cabeça, testando o codigo aqui, não sei pq local, ele roda normamente, mas no servidor da erro a array inicial   $arr = [1, 1, 1]; Sabe me dizer pq?

Comment: Tem mais detalhes do erro @MarcosPaulo?

Comment: So me fala que deu erro na linha 03
[22-Mar-2019 09:57:46 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/fxcompco/public_html/raspadinha/randon.php on line 3

Comment: Provavelmente é a versão do php, tente mudar para `$arr = array(1, 1, 1);`